# Keystone 6 js: checkbox null values

Tags: keystonejs, keystone, keystonejs6

Keystone js 6 does not allow me to add checkbox field, that looks the following way

```
// checkbox_field: checkbox({ label: 'Checkbox Field', access: { read: ()=> true, update: ()=> true } }),
```

I assume it's because I have some null values in db, since I had a the same problem with text type field, which was easily solved using db.isNullable === true. However, I can't find a similar option for checkbox field type.

I tried using defaultValue option and db.map, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what way does Keystone "not allow" this? Do you get an error? It's difficult to help with a problem without concrete information about what's happening.

I've added the field config you supplied to my local copy of the [task manager example](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/examples/usecase-task-manager) without issue.

```js
import { list } from '@keystone-6/core';
import { allowAll } from '@keystone-6/core/access';
import { checkbox, relationship, text, timestamp } from '@keystone-6/core/fields';
import { select } from '@keystone-6/core/fields';

export const lists = {
  Task: list({
    access: allowAll,
    fields: {
      label: text({ validation: { isRequired: true } }),

      // Test field ⬇️
      checkbox_field: checkbox({
        label: 'Checkbox Field',
        access: { read: () => true, update: () => true }
      }),
      
      // .. other fields
    },
  }),
  .. other lists
};
```

I've set `db.useMigrations` to `true` so when I restart the app, I'm prompted to create and name a migration that will add the column. The resultant SQL is below. This is for PostgreSQL but it should be for the other DB providers.

```sql
-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE "Task" ADD COLUMN     "checkbox_field" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false;
```

This will add a non-nullable column to the DB with the default value applied to any existing records (so there shouldn't be anything "blocking" this migration from applying).

For simplicity's sake the Keystone [Checkbox field type](https://keystonejs.com/docs/fields/checkbox) doesn't support the DB field itself being nullable though it does give you some options to control the nullability of the GraphQL types, ie: `graphql.read.isNonNull` and `graphql.create.isNonNull`. This allows for use cases where a value may be returned as `null` due to access control, or passed in as `null` for a create but saved with a value due to a default value or hook being configured.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try to explain my aim and problem in more details. I'm trying to switch my keystone 5 js project to keystone 6 js. My postgresql db has nullable checkbox fields and it worked fine with the fifth version. What I meant by Keystone 6 "not allow" this is that when I run my project using checkbox field that has null values in db, the whole list does not display the rows from db. However, when I get rid of null checkbox values in db everything works fine. I assume it's because as you said  Keystone Checkbox field type doesn't support the DB field being null, am I right?

Comment: Ooh you have an existing DB to migrate, I didn't realise. Yes, your theory sounds correct to me. Shouldn't be too hard to fix the DB though; something like..  `UPDATE table SET checkbox_field = false WHERE checkbox_field is null; ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN checkbox_field SET NOT NULL, ALTER COLUMN checkbox_field SET DEFAULT false;`